# devise password reset instructions email override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to override devise `reset_password_instructions`, and i want to send current application host in parameters in `opts` hash, how can i do this? I have tried to debug the code with `byebug` but could not find any answer. Please help.

```
# File 'app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb', line 10

def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
end
```

my passwords_controller.rb

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  before_filter :set_mailer_host

  def create
    super
  end

  def set_mailer_host
    Devise.mailer.default_url_options.merge!({host: request.host_with_port})
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-:host-and-:port-for-all-devise-mailer-urls

Comment: @DipakG. this is not helpful as i have to set host from request object and i cannot access `request` object in that concern.

Comment: What is it that you are tying to do again ?

Comment: @MZaragoza i am trying to add a key/value pair to `opts` argument in `reset_password_instructions` method.